# How to close togle by default?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a floating social share button that closed by default and will not open until the trigger is clicked.
I got some codes from the internet, but the problem is the social icons is open by default and cover the page, how can I make it close by default? This is the codes:

```js
const trigger = document.querySelector("menu > .trigger");
trigger.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.currentTarget.parentElement.classList.toggle("open");
});
```

```css
menu {
  --size: 2.1rem;
  --radius: 6rem;
  --padding: .5rem;
  --bg-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  --fg-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  --hi-color: #12192c;
  font-size: 29px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: var(--padding);
  right: var(--padding);
}

menu > * {
  position: absolute;
  
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 29px;
  background: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--fg-color);
  
  text-decoration: none;
  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

menu > .action {
  --factor: 0;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  right: calc(1.35 * var(--size));
  bottom: calc(1.35 * var(--size));
  
  opacity: 0;
  
  transform: rotate(calc(-1 * var(--angle))) translateY(calc(-1 * var(--radius) * var(--factor))) rotate(var(--angle));
  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out, opacity 250ms ease-in-out, box-shadow 250ms ease-in-out, color 250ms ease-in-out;
}

menu > .action:hover, menu > .trigger:hover {
  color: var(--hi-color);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0.35rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

menu.open > .action {
  --factor: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}

menu > .action:nth-child(1) {
  --angle: 0deg;
  transition-delay: 0ms;
}

menu > .action:nth-child(2) {
  --angle: 30deg;
  transition-delay: 50ms;
}

menu > .action:nth-child(3) {
  --angle: 60deg;
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}

menu > .action:nth-child(4) {
  --angle: 90deg;
  transition-delay: 150ms;
}



menu > .trigger {
  width: calc(1.3 * var(--size));
  height: calc(1.3 * var(--size));
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: box-shadow 250ms ease-in-out, color 250ms ease-in-out;
}

menu > .trigger > i {
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

menu.open > .trigger > i {
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<menu class="open">

   <a href="#" class="action"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="action"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="action"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="action"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger"><i class="fas fa-share"></i></a>
  
</menu>
  <script  src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

I got the codes here: https://www.learningrobo.com/2021/11/floating-social-media-buttons-using.html?sc=1659803757099#c6812736580691024803

Thank you.

Comment: change `<menu class="open">`  to `<menu class="">`

Answer (score 0):

change from `<menu class="open">` to `<menu class="">` in html.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this, you can use a hidden checkbox to open/close menu:

```css
.hidden
{
  display: none;
}

menu {
  --size: 2.1rem;
  --radius: 6rem;
  --padding: .5rem;
  --bg-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  --fg-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  --hi-color: #12192c;
  font-size: 29px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: var(--padding);
  right: var(--padding);
}

menu > * {
  position: absolute;
  
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 29px;
  background: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--fg-color);
  
  text-decoration: none;
  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

menu > .action {
  --factor: 0;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  right: calc(1.35 * var(--size));
  bottom: calc(1.35 * var(--size));
  
  opacity: 0;
  
  transform: rotate(calc(-1 * var(--angle))) translateY(calc(-1 * var(--radius) * var(--factor))) rotate(var(--angle));
  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out, opacity 250ms ease-in-out, box-shadow 250ms ease-in-out, color 250ms ease-in-out;
}

menu > .action:hover, menu > .trigger:hover {
  color: var(--hi-color);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0.35rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

menu > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .action { /* changed */
  --factor: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}

menu > .action:nth-child(2) { /* changed */
  --angle: 0deg;
  transition-delay: 0ms;
}

menu > .action:nth-child(3) { /* changed */
  --angle: 30deg;
  transition-delay: 50ms;
}

menu > .action:nth-child(4) { /* changed */
  --angle: 60deg;
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}

menu > .action:nth-child(5) { /* changed */
  --angle: 90deg;
  transition-delay: 150ms;
}

menu > .trigger {
  width: calc(1.3 * var(--size));
  height: calc(1.3 * var(--size));
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: box-shadow 250ms ease-in-out, color 250ms ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

menu > .trigger > i {
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

menu > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .trigger > i {  /* changed */
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<menu>
  <input id="trigger" class="hidden" type="checkbox">
  <a href="#" class="action"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="action"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="action"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="action"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
  <label for="trigger" class="trigger"><i class="fas fa-share"></i></label>
  
</menu>
  <script  src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```